# Setting spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY in spark-3. Does it implement fallback to older formatter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's consider `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY`.   I can not find answer for a following question:

Does it lead to fallback (in case of failure of new formatter (by new I mean formatter from spark-3)) to older formatters (from spark-2.x)?

It would mean that `LEGACY` mode make it possible to everything that is accepted by new formatter and everyting that is accepted by older formatters.

Comment: I think the logic is more complex. You can find the relevant code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4f1e434ec57070b52b28f98c66b53ca6ec4de7a4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala#L132)